# Как сортировать списки в списках?

Tags: c#, сортировка

У меня есть список "слова" в списке "предложения".
Мне нужно отсортировать список "предложения" так, чтобы в приоритете был список "слова", чьи элементы имеют большее значение по юникоду.
Боюсь, что я не смогу достаточно грамотно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому составил два примера.

```
List<List<string>> listForBigrams = new List<List<string>>();
```

На вход даётся:

```
{{"bbb","bbb"},{"aaa","aab"},{"aaa","aaa"}}
```

На выходе требуется:

```
{{"aaa","aaa"},{"aaa","aab"},{"bbb","bbb"}}
```

Comment: `var result = listForBigrams.SelectMany(x => x).OrderBy(x => x).Select((x, i) => (Index: i, Value: x)).GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2).Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value));` Правда я не до конца понял, что именно нужно. В моем примере идет именно сортировка элементов и потом последующее воссоздание списка по новой, где будет по 2 элемента. Если речь идет именно про сортировку самих массивов, то такое конечно не подойдет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужна сортировка listForBigrams для того, чтобы выбрать самые повторяющиеся "значения" (например listForBigrams [0][1]) для "ключей" ( listForBigrams[0][0]). Потом списки из этого списка (listForBigrams ) будут записаны в словарь, где первый элемент будет ключом, а второй - значением этого ключа

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский